# How to export Safari Web Inspector timeline data?

Tags: safari, webkit, google-chrome-devtools, safari-extension, web-inspector

Just like in Chrome Developer Tool, I was wondering if there is any tool/extension/plugin which would allow me to export timeline data in Safari. I tried the nightly build of webkit but it does not have that feature. Seems like this is a Chrome specific functionality.

I have to use Safari because I am testing a webapp on iPhone.

I searched around for any hints but could not get any. As of now I am thinking of two options to get the timeline information:

- Build a Safari extension
- Get Chrome Dev Tool's timeline code and build my own version of webkit (if that's even possible!)

Any guides/insights would be highly appreciated!

**Update 1**: I downloaded Webkit and found out that it supports remote iPhone debugging through USB. Probably I can find the code for web inspector for Webkit and use that code to export the timeline data.

Comment: This has been a known issue since 2008: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19227

Comment: Oh nevermind, this has been fixed for a while I guess: https://twitter.com/xeenon/status/1177288870401957888

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Safari's Web inspector does use the WebKit remote debugging protocol.
>   However, Safari does not use TCP/HTTP as a transport layer, thus
>   making it incompatible with Chrome. [source](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/158126)

Thankfully, someone from Google wrote a [proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy) allowing to overcome this limitation.

Comment: awesome! this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Please note that the above no longer works for Timeline/Profiling, apparently there's been significant divergence since 2013 :(

Comment: The proxy only works for iOS unfortunately. No support for JSContext/WKWebView on macOS. 